# Display duration in milliseconds

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I want to display duration with milliseconds on a web page. So far I have done this: 
I managed to display this output on a label: **00:02:50**, but I want to display milliseconds as well, so the result should look like this **00:02:50:000**. How do I achieve this?

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
    // sleep for 2.5s
    Thread.Sleep(2500);
    DateTime stopTime = DateTime.Now;
    TimeSpan duration = stopTime - startTime;
    Result.Text = duration.ToString("mm':'ss':'ff");
}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

First of all, if you're timing things I would recommend using the StopWatch class as that's what it's there for.  You can find it in the System.Diagnostics namespace: `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`.

You can instantiate a new one and start measuring the elapsed amount of time with one line of code: `var stop = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();` and then stop the timer with the stop method: `stop.Stop();`.  You can then return the elapsed time using the Elapsed property `var elapsed = stop.Elapsed;`.

Then in order to display the elapsed time with milliseconds you would call the ToString method on the elapsed timespan with the correct parameters.

So putting it all together your code would look like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var timer = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
    // sleep for 2.5s
    Thread.Sleep(2500);
    timer.Stop();
    var elapsed = timer.Elapsed;
    Result.Text = elapsed.ToString("mm':'ss':'fff");
}
```

Hope that helps!

James

Comment: Brilliant answer, indeed I am timing sql query.

Answer (score 7):

Your current code should be displaying **minutes, seconds, and hundredths of a second**.

```
Result.Text = duration.ToString("mm':'ss':'ff");
```

To display milliseonds instead of hundredths of a second:

```
// output: 00:02:500
Result.Text = duration.ToString("mm':'ss':'fff");
```

See the documentation for [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

The [doc says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx): "fff" gives you:

> The milliseconds in a date and time value.

You're using "ff" which gives you:

> The hundredths of a second in a date and time value.

So, change your code to:

```
duration.ToString("mm':'ss':'fff");
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you're confused. In your case `00:02:50` means 2 seconds and 50 hundredths of second. If you want to display milliseconds, use format like `mm':'ss':'fff` (notice the one added `f`). This will print something like `00:02:500`, i.e. 2 seconds and 500 thousandths of second, or 2 s 500 ms.

**But this doesn't mean your measurements will be precise down to millisecond.** That's not what `DateTime.Now` is meant to do. If you want to make measurements this precise, you should use [`StopWatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Indeed, I was confused.

Answer (score 3):

Use [TimeSpan.ToString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ecy8h51.aspx) with custom format.

The returned string is formatted with the "c" format specifier and has the following format:

```
[-][d.]hh:mm:ss[.fffffff]
```

Elements in square brackets ([ and ]) may not be included in the returned string. Colons and periods (: and.) are literal characters.

```
Result.Text = duration.ToString("mm:ss:fff");
```

or

```
Result.Text = duration.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff");
```

Ref :[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx), [The "fff" Custom Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#fffSpecifier)

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2008, 8, 29, 19, 27, 15, 18);
CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff", ci));
// Displays 07:27:15.018
```

Answer (score 2):

Otherwise just use the properties from the timespan like this:

```
var result = String.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", duration.Minutes, duration.Seconds, duration.Milliseconds);
Result.Text = result
```

This way I think you gain more control over what you want to display, instead of formatting the timespan in the ToString()-method which more easily allows typos to be made...

Hope this helps!

**Update:**
To add the hours as well this is how it'll look like:

```
var result = String.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}:{3}", duration.Hours, duration.Minutes, duration.Seconds, duration.Milliseconds);
```